# Adding a return function to Truffles Pet Shop

Tags: solidity

I am following the Truffle tutorials, and am on https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop. I would like to add a return function that sets the adopters[PetId] in the solidity contract back to the 0 address. I currently have:

```
    function returnPet(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;
    }
```

in my Adoption.sol

and in my app.js is:

```
  handleReturn: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

    var adoptionInstance;

    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        adoptionInstance = instance;

        return adoptionInstance.returnPet(petId);
      }).then(function(result) {
        return App.markAdopted();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
```

but it hits the catch and returns: invalid address.

In short:

How do I zero out an address in an array of addresses?*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code in `returnPet()` sets the `adopters[petId]` value to `msg.sender`, which means "the caller address".

> *I would like to add a return function that sets the adopters[PetId] in the solidity contract back to the 0 address*

You can do it by setting the value to `address(0)`.

So your function will then look like

```
function returnPet(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

    adopters[petId] = address(0);

    return petId;
}
```

Comment: I changed ```msg.sender``` to ```address(0)``` and the JS function still hits the catch and returns invalid address. A test I wrote passes, but the JS function still does not work.

Comment: Running ```contract.returnPet(2)``` in Truffles console also works.

Comment: @SeanLindorff It seems you need to set up `defaults` of your contract instance. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12960

Comment: I've defined web3.eth.defaultAccount as web3.eth.accounts[0], but now all my actions generate 3 transactions each. The return button now generates transactions, but does not actually affect the block chain. I've defined web3.eth.defaultAccount inside of the handleReturn function. I attempted defining it after I init web3, but it results in the same behavior. Sorry if this is grounds for a new question or not.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with the JS part so I don't know why it would send 3 transactions. It's probably better if you submit a new question with `web3js` tag so someone who understands this topic better can give better answer.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!